# XML processing using SAX or STAX

Tags: java, xml, sax, stax

I am new to JAVA programming and Parsers to process XML files, now I in need of JAVA program to read a big XML file that containing .. tags. Sample input as follows.

my previous xml file is .

```
<employees>
    <Employee id="1">
        <age>29</age>
        <name>Pankaj</name>
        <gender>Male</gender>
        <role>Java Developer</role>
    </Employee>
    <Employee id="2">
        <age>35</age>
        <name>Lisa</name>
        <gender>Female</gender>
        <role>CEO</role>
    </Employee>
</employee>

New `Input.xml`:

    <row>
    <Name>Filename1</Name>
    </row>
    <row>
    <Name>Filename2</Name>
    </row>
    <row>
    <Name>Filename3</Name>
    </row>
```

I need output as first `<row> </row>` as a single `.xml` file with filename as `filename1.xml` and second `<row>..</row>` as `filename2.xml` and so.

```
I have tried something like:

Using this code we can split the xml document which contains below format.But this code not supported by new aim that was mentioned in the above question.my source code is,



import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileReader;
import javax.xml.stream.XMLInputFactory;
import javax.xml.stream.XMLStreamConstants;
import javax.xml.stream.XMLStreamReader;
import javax.xml.transform.Transformer;
import javax.xml.transform.TransformerFactory;
import javax.xml.transform.stax.StAXSource;
import javax.xml.transform.stream.StreamResult;


public class Big {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception  {
        XMLInputFactory xif = XMLInputFactory.newInstance();            
        XMLStreamReader xsr = xif.createXMLStreamReader(new FileReader("input.xml"));
        xsr.nextTag();
         TransformerFactory tf = TransformerFactory.newInstance();
        Transformer t = tf.newTransformer();
        while(xsr.nextTag() == XMLStreamConstants.START_ELEMENT) {       

            File file = new File("output1/" +  xsr.getAttributeValue(null,"id") + ".xml");
            t.transform(new StAXSource(xsr), new StreamResult(file));

        }

    }

} 

my previous xml file is .

<employees>
    <Employee id="1">
        <age>29</age>
        <name>Pankaj</name>
        <gender>Male</gender>
        <role>Java Developer</role>
    </Employee>
    <Employee id="2">
        <age>35</age>
        <name>Lisa</name>
        <gender>Female</gender>
        <role>CEO</role>
    </Employee>
</employee>
```

It gives output as 1.xml,2.xml...but now my aim is different my file name should be the content inside   tag .

Should i modify the source code to get outcome og my new aim.If it is possible can you send the modified source code???  I used STAX parser

Can you please guide us?

Thanks,

Sowmiya

Comment: Have you tried anything? Show us your code.

Comment: i have tried related to this xml file

Comment: i have attached my code below my question.Thanks for Your kind reply

Answer (score 1):

Replace

```
xsr.getAttributeValue(null,"id")
```

with

```
xsr.getElementText()
```

Comment: It throws an exception

Comment: because my new xml does not contains main tag which covers entire document.The old xml dile contains the parent tag <employees></employess> inside this tag i has different document.please have lokk on to my old xml and new xml file.Can you please give some suggeations to me?

Comment: The exception is like:Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalStateException: StAXSource(XMLStream
Reader) with XMLStreamReadernot in XMLStreamConstants.START_DOCUMENT or XMLStrea
mConstants.START_ELEMENT state
        at javax.xml.transform.stax.StAXSource.<init>(StAXSource.java:155)
        at Big.main(Big.java:23)